# Is the order of evaluation considered when analyzing ownership in an expression?

Tags: rust

In Rust 1.0, does the compiler consider order of evaluation when analyzing ownership in an expression?  For example:

```
struct Foo { val:usize }

fn main() {
    let mut v:Vec<Foo> = Vec::with_capacity(1);
    v.push(Foo{val:0});

    let f = Foo{val:0};
    v[f.val] = f; // error: use of moved value
}
```

Fails to compile because the index into the array is `f.val`, while `f` is being moved into the array.  I do not see why using `f.val` as an index on the LHS can be in conflict with the transfer of ownership of 'f' on the RHS.

Comment: Based on your example, it appears that the transfer of ownership of `f` happens before `f.val` is evaluated. It seems like you have answered your own question. What more information would you like to see?

Comment: @Shepmaster, f.val has to be evaluated before the transfer of ownership, since before such time, the destination doesn't exist, may be out of bounds, etc.

Comment: @Shepmaster, On second thought, if the assignment operator is not a sequence point in Rust, then the compiler's complaint is fair.  I suppose this is like the foo() = bar() ambiguity in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you derive `Clone` and `Copy` for your struct, after that the value will not move, but it will be just copied, which solves your problem (the value will no longer be moved) and is effective as well, since the struct is quite small.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Foo { val: usize }
```

**Update**

In case you don't want to derive `Copy` you can easily overcome this issue by copying the index first and only do the assignment after:

```
let index = f.val; // usize is copyable, so no moves here
v[index] = f;
```

This obviously forces the order of evaluation.

Comment: the struct is only small for the purpose of creating an MWE.

Comment: I updated the answer according to the struct not being so small in reality.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is not well-defined at the language level, though obviously the compiler has to do *something*.